# iOS facebook import image library grabkit or others?

Tags: ios, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, photo

I'm using the library grabkit, this is for import images from facebook/flickr/dropbox...
I use it mainly for facebook import image.

1. Grabkit seems long time to commit, and FB change graph API into 2.0.  Is there any problem ? Do you have other suggestions? Or I need to implement it myself? Grabkit's spec totally meet my requirement, but it shows error for my FB account.
2. When I browse one of my facebook albums. most album seems work fine.
   It shows some errors. album cover photo can't show up and photos in the album are less than it actually has.
   Here're the graphpath and params.

   ```
   FB graphPath={result=coverPhotoId_1594748244149:$.cover_photo}
   FB params={
   fields = "id,name,created_time,updated_time,images,height,width";
    locale = "zh_TW";}
   ```

Here're errors.

```
error for cover data album 1442019266020 : Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation     
couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x19c3dbe0 
{com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 100;
        message = "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api";
        type = GraphMethodException;
    };
};
code = 400;
headers =     (
            {
        name = Connection;
        value = close;
    },
            {
        name = "WWW-Authenticate";
        value = "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_request\" \"Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api\"";
    },
            {
        name = "Facebook-API-Version";
        value = "v1.0";
    },
            {
        name = "Content-Type";
        value = "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8";
    },
            {
        name = Pragma;
        value = "no-cache";
    },
            {
        name = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
        value = "*";
    },
            {
        name = "Cache-Control";
        value = "no-store";
    },
            {
        name = Expires;
        value = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
);
},    
 com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x188cebf0, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x188cef10, appID: 419719574779916, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x195739f0>, expirationDate: 2014-09-26 08:02:28 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-07-28 10:12:29 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
"basic_info",
"user_photo_video_tags",
"user_photos",
installed,
"user_videos",
"public_profile",
"user_friends"
)>}
```

Comment: Without third party see this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New created Facebook Apps (created after 7th August 2014) are not working anymore because they use Facebook API 2.1 and this doesn't allow fql anymore. If you use a newly created Facebook app you will get the error you had.

Facebook API 2.0 will deprecate on August 7, 2016

When you use an app that was created earlier it still works. (So it uses FB API 2.0)

One hint for me was this answer: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259915/fqlquery-for-recent-facebook-api)