# How to use FQL in newer Facebook apps (created after 7th August 2014)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to use FQL for my app because the newer Graph API does not yet have support for what I want to do. For this, I came to know that my app must be created before 7th August, 2014 ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256428/query-facebook-for-what-version-of-the-graph-api-is-being-used-can-be-used) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259915/fqlquery-for-recent-facebook-api)). The apps created before that date can still use FQL while Graph API is not yet suitable for all needs.
However, I don't have any apps created before that date which I can use to run FQL queries. Even while creating new apps, we don't get an option to specify its api version. How do I use FQL in newly created apps?

PS: I want to fetch all messages in a conversation with a friend while enforcing some constraints. There is a simple FQL query for doing this while I was not able to achieve this using the newer graph API.

Comment: Can I know why this question was downvoted? I did my research and made efforts to make the question clear. What is amiss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: You can´t use FQL in newer Apps, there is no workaround.

But there is something else that may be important for you, for fetching messages you would need to use the `read_mailbox` permission, and you would need to get it approved in order to make it available for everyone. Without approval, it will only work for users with a role in your App (Admin/Dev/Tester). And `read_mailbox` only gets approved for platforms without a native Facebook experiece:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.